# How to manage a Git merge conflict with xlsx (binary)?

Tags: git, git-merge

How to manage a Git merge conflict with xlsx (binary)?

It requested to fix the conflict:

```
$ git merge  
warning: Cannot merge binary files: proj/data/specs.xlsx (HEAD vs. 
refs/remotes/origin/master)
Auto-merging proj/data/specs.xlsx
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in proj/data/specs.xlsx
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I want get the `origin/master` version of the file

```
git add proj/data/specs.xlsx; git commit
```

it keep my local version of the file.

If I checkout the file I get this error:

```
$ git checkout labor_um/data/UM_specs.xlsx
error: path 'labor_um/data/UM_specs.xlsx' is unmerged
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do:

```
git checkout --theirs proj/data/specs.xlsx
git add proj/data/specs.xlsx
git commit
```

The `--theirs` flag for the `checkout` command tells Git to use the version from the branch you are merging (in this case `origin/master`). Similarly, the `--ours` flag would use the version from the branch you are on (likely `master`).

Note that [the definition of `--theirs` and `--ours` is swapped during a `rebase`](//stackoverflow.com/a/25576672/2747593).

Answer (score 3):

```
git checkout --theirs proj/data/specs.xlsx
```

should take the version of the `xlsx` file on the `origin` and ignore your modified version.

It should fix the conflict then you need to commit it.